# Replacement for System.Drawing.Image for Save, Load and convert to base64

Tags: c#, .net, azure-cosmosdb, cross-platform, system.drawing

Recently I started to get warnings such as:
`CA1416: This call site is reachable on all platforms. 'Image' is only supported on: 'windows'.`. When I looked for more information about it I found that Microsoft [broke compatibility and no longer supports `System.Drawing.Image` on platforms other than Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/6.0/system-drawing-common-windows-only).

Their recommendation is to switch to one of the following libraries:

- [SkiaSharp](https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp)
- [ImageSharp](https://sixlabors.com/products/imagesharp) (tiered license)
- [Microsoft.Maui.Graphics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/graphics/)

**Some context:**

- I only use `System.Drawing.Image` to Save, Load and convert to Base64 (in order to render it in HTML)
- While I do only very basic stuff with it, I use it as part of an internal library that is used throughout the company on multiple projects
- It's part of the public interface of this library
- These projects have to run on both Windows, Mac and Linux
- As it's an internal project, relying on a licensed product is out of the question, so probably **ImageSharp** is out of the question, which leaves me with either **SkiaSharp** or **Microsoft.Maui.Graphics**.
- I only get the warning on a call to `Image.FromFile`, and in unit-tests that use it with [Moq](https://github.com/devlooped/moq) as `It.IsAny<Image>()`

**I have two questions:**

1. As **SkiaSharp** and **Maiu.Graphics** have their own classes to represent an image, does it mean that I must break backwards compatibility in my library?
2. I couldn't find any simple example for either of these libraries, for just saving, loading and converting an image to base64. Can you provide me with such examples?

**Update:**
I just noticed a couple of interesting facts:

- The call to `Image.FromFile` is also from a test. This doesn't matter much though, as these tests need also to run on Linux (on a GitHub Actions runner)
- The problem started when I added a reference to **Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos** in *another project* in the solution. While both this project and the test project where the warnings appear, (transitively) depend on a common project that use `System.Drawing.Image`, neither of these two projects depend on the other one. I find it very strange that adding a reference to one project affects a different projects that don't depend on it...

Comment: Do you actually need to use the `Image` object for anything? If you just need the data to convert to base-64 then `File.ReadAllBytes` will provide the same data.

Comment: From the page you linked to: *"Alternatively, you can enable support for non-Windows platforms in .NET 6 by setting the System.Drawing.EnableUnixSupport runtime configuration switch to true in the runtimeconfig.json file"*. Any reason you can't do that, given that your needs are limited and unlikely to be affected if you have already tested thoroughly on non-Windows platforms.

Comment: _"does it mean that I must break backwards compatibility in my library?"_ - I would actually _recommend_ you release a new breaking major version that _does not_ make any types that are specific to any of those libs part of its public api.

Comment: _"I couldn't find any simple example for either of these libraries, for just saving, loading and converting an image to base64."_ What exactly do are you struggling with? You take the images byte[] and convert it to Base64 ... that's not really specific to any of these libs.

Comment: ^^ _and_ it has been asked before, so you'll even find questions and answer here. Is there anything you need that [`Convert.ToBase64String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tobase64string?view=net-7.0) does not do? Or the recommended streaming alternative [ToBase64Transform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.tobase64transform?view=net-7.0) ?

Comment: @jmcilhinney AFAIU, setting System.Drawing.EnableUnixSupport is only a temporary workaround and will no longer work in .Net 7. Regarding the use of `File.ReadAllBytes` instead, that's an interesting idea that I haven't considered, but in public API I expect an Image that should be rendered on an HTML page, so while I can get any byte-array it won't be a nice strongly-typed API...

Comment: @Fildor, regarding breaking compatibility, Of course I prefer not to add a dependency on 3rd party libraries in my API, but the question is what's the alternative?

Comment: I don't know your API, so it's hard to tell. But our internal Image Processing Lib only takes and returns either binary image data as `byte[]` or base64 encoded as `ReadOnlySpan<char>`.

Comment: @Fildor regarding the examples I found, mainly for saving and loading image files, I may have not read thoroughly enough, but at least the first Google results did not provide a clear and concise answer. However I used ChatGpt now and found that it's not so complicated indeed (assuming it's not hallucinating).

Comment: Well, if you don't alter image content (resize, touch up, change format ... ) then it's basically transparent to you and you can treat it as you would any other peace of binary data, including File I/O.